# How to remove the 5s delay of the Silverlight Unit Testing Framework

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, testing, silverlight-toolkit

I use the Silverlight Unit Testing Framework and it works pretty well.

However every time I launch my tests, I have to wait 5 seconds or click the "*No, run all tests*" button.

Is there a way to skip this step that I don't need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the App.xaml.cs:

Replace

```
RootVisual = UnitTestSystem.CreateTestPage();
```

With

```
UnitTestSettings settings = UnitTestSystem.CreateDefaultSettings();
settings.StartRunImmediately = true;
settings.ShowTagExpressionEditor = false;

RootVisual = UnitTestSystem.CreateTestPage(settings);
```